# Does the Z-function ever touch the x-axis without crosssing it

Tags: number-theory, riemann-zeta

I've been reading about methods to compute zeros of the riemann-zeta function by finding sign changes of the Z-function, but the paper I was reading didn't address whether or not it was possible for the Z-function to just touch the x-axis without crosssing it.

Can this happen?
And if not, why not?

Thanks!

Edit: In the comments there was a bit of confusion over what the Z-function is, by the Z-function I'm referring to [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z_function).

Comment: This method of sign changing doesn't work as the zeta function is a complex valued analytic function. So you might want to be careful by how you mean by "crossing" the x-axis.

Comment: The Z-function isn't the zeta function, Z(t)=e^(i\theta(t))*\zeta(1/2 + it). This function is real whenever t is real, and zero whenever \zeta(1/2+it) is real.
 

I'll edit the question to clarify that though, thanks!

Comment: whoops sorry!  :/

Comment: Don't worry, it happens to everyone.

Comment: It's conjectured that the zeta-function has no multiple zeros.

Comment: Is that equivilant to this? Or is this stronger?

Comment: It is conjectured that $Z(t)$ has no even order zeros, so it is conjectured that the case you mention doesn't exist. 

Now there is another problematic case : if $Z(t)$ has a triple zero at $t_0$ then the sign change shows it has a real zero at $t_0$, but it will be almost impossible to distinguish the triple zero from $3$ simple zeros (at $t_0, t_0+\epsilon,t_0+\delta$ with $\epsilon,\delta$ real or complex conjugate).

That's why we are pleased to conjecture that $Z(t)$ (thus $\zeta(s)$) has only simple zeros.